# Changing the display of graph

Tags: python, graph

I have obtained the following graph using python.

[image]

Is there a built-in function in python that I can use to **shift the graph?**
so that the whole graph will shift to the position where at the point where y-coordinate is 0.5 will appear in the center of the graph.

so I will just get the following bit.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your code? Also, please explain exactly what you want, it's not clear at the moment.

Comment: @Ffisegydd:
I have uploaded a picture of what I want, sorry that my wording was not great, if you have any idea to improve my wording, please do edit

Answer (score 0):

You can put the axis origin at any data point, it would look like this

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data', 2.1))
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 0.5))
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
```